# Convert Tensor to CUDA in Pytorch C++, But the content changed

Tags: c++, pytorch

everyone, I'm facing a problem that I need to copy a tensor to CUDA. The code are as follows:

```html
torch::Tensor r_data1 = torch::from_blob(raw_data.data(), {batch_size, arr_size}).to(torch::kInt64);
auto tmp_data = static_cast<size_t*>(r_data1.storage().data());
size_t tmp_size = r_data1.numel();
cout << "r data1 tensor ";
for (size_t i = 0; i < tmp_size; i++) {
    cout << tmp_data[i] << "\t";
}
cout << endl;

torch::Tensor r_data2 = r_data1.cuda();
tmp_data = static_cast<size_t*>(r_data2.cpu().storage().data());
tmp_size = r_data2.numel();
cout << "r data tensor ";
for (size_t i = 0; i < tmp_size; i++) {
    cout << tmp_data[i] << "\t";
}
cout << endl;
```

But the results are:

**r data1 tensor** 101  4886    2456    4689    3787    2336    2356    1298    2128    2356    4886    2456    4689 1298   2128    2356    736 6963    7252    5401    3215    3333    1921    3441    8110    1384
**r data tensor** 139682015587936   139682014923568 2456    4689    3787    2336    2356    1298    2128    2356    4886 2456   4689    1298    2128    2356    736 6963    7252    5401    3215    3333    1921    3441    8110    1384

The ids have been changed. Why? Have you come into this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what your code did. I believe your `static_cast<size_t*>(r_data1.storage().data());` is not doing what you think it does. If you need to access the data in a tensor; you should just use normal indexing: e.g. `r_data1[i]`. I am mostly familiar with the python interface. On which there is no `data` parameter on a `Storage`. There is a `data_ptr()`, and I think that's what you are accessing. If you need to access your elements in a flat tensor, you can use `r_data1_flat = r_data1.flatten()`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try.

Comment: I have fixed this problem. I fount the problem did not happen when the system copy data from cpu to cuda, instead it happened when data were moved from cuda to cpu. I change the code to:   std::vector<size_t> predict_ori_labels(result.data<std::int64_t>(), result.data<std::int64_t>() + result.numel()); And done!